# How to secure APIs for mobile Application without login authentication

Tags: laravel, jwt, mobile-development, laravel-sanctum

I am working on a project to develop a mobile app using Laravel 8.

I have used Laravel sanctum for generating tokens and User authentication.

My project requires to call certain APIs prior to user login for displaying general data on the mobile app. What would be the best way to secure those APIs? I do not want anyone to call those APIs and retrieve information for their own purposes